# What happened from you touch the screen till iOS app receive the click event?

Tags: html, ios, uiwebview, wkwebview

There is a button in the middle of an app. After you touch the screen and click on it, you receive a click event on the button. What happened in the middle?

I used to face a bug, use the UIWebView, one input element in an HTML can't response the click event, but the WkWebview can.

Now I want to confirm the question below:

What happened from you touch the screen till iOS app receive the click event?

After I had viewed the Woodstock's answer. I edit this question.

Don't consider the hardware, just think the iOS system.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple events triggered, for example:

Finger down, Finger moved, Finger Up.

Additionally there are events for where that occurred, e.g. inside or outside a control.

If you are asking what's happening in the quantum between contact with the capacitive display and the processing of the event by iOS this is not well defined.

Suffice to say, clock cycles and processing :)